# How to restore chrome tabs after my Mac got crashed and was subject to reboot automatically?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, restore, crash

My Mac got crashed and was forced to be restarted automatically. And so my Chrome and Chromium session were gone too, on which when I opened them after the reboot of my Mac, "restore the last session" or some messages like that were shown on the screen. However, despite me clicking on the "restore" button, it didn't restore those tabs I opened! So the 30 tabs that I opened in my browser were all gone, and I'm quite disappointed.

However, is it still feasible to restore those tabs there were there before the OS X crash? I think [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/635436/can-i-restore-closed-tabs-after-quitting-chrome) might be what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it's not for OS X.

I use OS X 10.9.3 and the latest version of Chrome and Chromium. I have defaults files in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/`.